# How to set CPU frequency as early as possible?

Tags: boot, scripts, cpu

What I mean by this question is the sequence of execution of scripts at boot time.

Suppose I have this line of script:

```
echo 307000 > /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_min_freq
```

I want this line of script to be executed as soon as possible (even before android shell is loaded). Where is the best place to put it? (`init.d`?)